Panic Handler in Embedded Rust
I am setting up a new embedded rust project, and I encountered the "can't find crate for test" problem at the #![no_std]. I know it is because of adding the core crate for panic handler.
main.rs:
#![no_std]
#![no_main]


use core::panic::PanicInfo;


#[panic_handler]
    fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
        loop {}
    }

I tried adding the core crate to cargo, but it generates an error saying that the crate core could not be found in registry index.
I'm not sure what I must do next.

Please add the complete error message by cargo check or similar, the error "can't find crate for test" doesn't have anything to do with core being found, it should just be available as it's automatically included in the extern prelude

What chip are you programming for? The correct invocation of the compiler varies a lot between them.
